# Passing JSON strings to Django templates

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why I can't pass a JSON string generated from a Django Model into a template's javascript static file. As it turns out, the problem wasn't at the Model level (using serializers.serialize) - putting an identical string in the script itself will successfully parse, but passing the string in will not:

views.py:

```
def texas(request):
    test_json = '{"incidents": [{"field1": 1, "field2": 2}], "debug": 1}'
    return render(request, 'tx/texas.html', {'tx': test_json})
```

tx/texas.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<html>
    <head>
      <title>texas map</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id='texas'></p>
        <script>
            function load_texas() {
                return '{{ tx }}';
            }
        </script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/texas.js' %}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

js/texas.js fails with *JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data*:

```
var json_data = load_texas();

var paragraph = document.getElementById('texas');
try {
    paragraph.innerHTML = JSON.parse(json_data);
}
catch(err) {
    paragraph.innerHTML = err.message;
}
```

but is successful if the same string is just entered in the script:

```
// this JSON string is identical to the one passed in views.py
var json_data = '{"incidents": [{"field1": 1, "field2": 2}], "debug": 1}';
```

Am I missing something about the way Django handles context variables?

## Edit:

Not quite a fix for passing a string, but I'm now passing a JSON object directly to the template which solves my original problem of getting Models into javascript.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core import serializers
import json
from .models import Tx

def texas(request):
    tx_database = Tx.objects.all()

    # Django serialize puts square brackets around the string,
    # so slice them off.
    json_string = serializers.serialize('json', tx_database)[1:-1]

    # Load string into JSON object... is this best practice?
    test_json = json.loads(json_string)
    return render(request, 'tx/texas.html', {'tx': test_json})
```

Comment: Have you checked how the html looks after loading (e.g. with the Chrome developer tools etc.)? Could there be double quotes around the json string?

Comment: @ger.s.brett The text appears in the html without quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to disable autoescaping.

```
return '{{ tx|safe }}';
```

Note, you really should not create JSON data as strings in your view; create it as a Python datastructure, then use `json.dumps()`.

Comment: I forgot about using `safe`, but it didn't seem to make a difference when passing a string. You can see in my edited question I started passing my Models as a JSON object using `json.loads()` (because the Django `serializer` module spits out a string representation), which works, but are there better Django practices than this?

Comment: No that doesn't make sense. Why do you want to convert the JSON back into Python data structures before passing to the template?

Comment: You're right, that doesn't make sense. It was working for the simple example above (how?) but now I'm getting `ReferenceError: None is not defined`.