# How to create Bar Chart in django using database value

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, charts

hello everyone i want to create a bar chart using my database value in django i am create a model that is

```
class statictab(models.Model):
    def indiantime():
        date = now() + timedelta(minutes = 330)
        return date.date()
    user = models.ForeignKey(usertab,on_delete = True)
    date = models.DateField(default=indiantime)
    click = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

i have save last 10 days click of every user in my database so i have fillter user last 10 days data like this

this is views.py

```
def createchart(request):
    if request.session.has_key('user_id'):
        pastdate = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=9) + timedelta(minutes=330)
        nowdate = timezone.now() + timedelta(minutes=330)
        staticdata = statictab.objects.filter(date__range=[pastdate.date() , nowdate.date() ],user_id=request.session['user_id'])
        d={"data" : staticdata}
        return return render(request,"html/chart.html",d)
```

in my `d` dictionary last 10 days data are present so i want to create a bar chart using chart.js so how i cant do this in my tamplate

my template chart.html

```
<html>
<head>

#all script and css are linked

</head>


<body>
<div id = "mychart">   

</div>

<script>
window.onload = function () {

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("mychart", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    title:{
        text: "Last 10 Days View"
    },
    axisX:{
        // valueFormatString: "DD MMM"
    },
    axisY: {
        title: "Number of Click",
    },
    data: [{
        type: "line",
        xValueFormatString: "DD MMM",
        color: "#F08080",
        dataPoints: [
            // { x: new Date(2017, 0, 7), y: 734 },
            // { x: new Date(2017, 0, 8), y: 963 },
            // { x: new Date(2017, 0, 9), y: 847 },
            // { x: new Date(2017, 0, 10), y: 853 }
            # how i give my database value on this place for create chart using for loop or other methord

        ]
    }]
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Found two related SO questions and this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/RPc18byRZX0 (this question isn't about bar charts, it's about sending data from django to js; always narrow down your problem to its core)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing JSON strings to Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45024069/passing-json-strings-to-django-templates)